# Is it possible to decompile the password protected rar file?

Tags: decompilation, executable

I'm trying to crack winrar's password using some methods as explained below.

Because rar uses AES-128 encryption, brute-force and dictionary attacks are useless as they would take years.
But, if we convert a password-protected rar file into an SFX archive

I used w32dasm, olly dbg & pe explorer to modify these exe files.
All I could find are the strings like "Extracting, CRC failed, Encrypted" and some other things. I used several sfx archives as test files (with different passwords) and tried it through disassembly. Those hexadecimal keys are looking quite similar!

So do I need a better disassembler or debugger?Am i on the right way or anyother way to decompile it.

My main aim was to extract the password protected file and ensure the file is safe,I already refered this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/145167/is-zips-encryption-really-bad) stating that it is possible only by brute forcing the winrar file.

Some of my win32dasm snapshots were as below :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to decompile the password protected rar file?

Decompilation is for code. RAR files are data. So **no**, there's nothing in a RAR file to decompile.

> But, if we convert a password-protected rar file into an SFX archive

Then you could decompile the SFX stub, but it still wouldn't allow you to decrypt the RAR data without the password.